# Why are Two same string variables not equal? Is it because of the byte array size?

Tags: arrays, string, go

Is the comparison false because of the byte size for **strBytes** that's been set for the string?

```
str := "test"

strBytes := make([]byte, 10)
copy(strBytes[:], str)

str1 := strings.TrimSpace(string(strBytes))

//why is this comparison false even though the string object is same => "test"
compare := str == str1

fmt.Printf("%v == %v = %v", str, str1, compare)
```

[Go playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/8jI7_nx_xQK)

Comment: Print with `fmt.Printf("%q == %q = %v", str, string(strBytes), compare)` to see what's happening.  The rune `\x00` is not trimmed from the string because `\x00` is not a space.

Comment: Or, print with `%#v`: https://play.golang.org/p/s3RDho8of_O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string(strBytes)` isn't identical to `str`, because it contains non printable runes. You can check if rune is printable with [`unicode.IsPrint` method](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsPrint). [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/8ZhsCyi1CXh) is code that shows non printable runes in `strBytes`:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "unicode"
    "unicode/utf8"
)

func main() {
    str := "test"
    strBytes := make([]byte, 8)
    copy(strBytes[:], str)

    for len(strBytes) > 0 {
        r, size := utf8.DecodeRune(strBytes)
        fmt.Printf("Char: %q; Printable: %v\n", r, unicode.IsPrint(r))

        strBytes = strBytes[size:]
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop iterates over bytes, not runes.  The  rune type conversions in the code hints at the problem.  Here's the correct loop: https://play.golang.org/p/hlSufwesaFr